# Error Code: 1422 Explicit or implicit commit is not allowed in stored function or trigger. when calling sp in trigger

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, database-trigger

What am I doing wrong ?

Create a trigger that automatically calls the payFees procedure whenever a film is returned.

You will have to decide how to name the trigger, when to fire it and for what table to fire it:

```
DROP TRIGGER trig_pay_fee;

DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER trig_pay_fee AFTER
UPDATE ON rental
FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    CALL payFees(new.rental_id);
  END//
DELIMITER ;

CALL returnFilm(1216);
```

Create a stored procedure payFees that records the payment of any overdue
fees when returning a film. The company charges €1 per day that a film is overdue.
Your procedure should update the row in the payments table
relating to them film by adding €1 to the amount per day overdue.

```
USE sakila;
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS payFees;
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE payFees(IN r_id INT)
  BEGIN

    IF daysOverdue(r_id) > 100
    THEN ALTER TABLE payment
      MODIFY COLUMN amount DECIMAL(10, 2);
    END IF;

    UPDATE payment
    SET amount = daysOverdue(r_id) * 1
    WHERE rental_id = r_id;

  END//
DELIMITER ;


CALL payFees(126);
SELECT *
FROM payment
WHERE rental_id = 126;
```